Log shipping via Transact-SQL failed
I wanted to set SQL Server Log shipping via T-SQL. So I set it up in GUI firstly and it was succesfull, replicated database on slave server occurred.
I did this step again for another database and this time I generated SQL transcript of this operation and didn't finish this operation and afterwards I tried run generate SQL code on master and slave.
Here is the code:

-- Execute the following statements at the Primary to configure Log Shipping 
-- for the database [172.21.23.16].[NewDB9],
-- The script needs to be run at the Primary in the context of the [msdb] database.  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- Adding the Log Shipping configuration 

-- ****** Begin: Script to be run at Primary: [172.21.23.16] ******


DECLARE @LS_BackupJobId AS uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_PrimaryId   AS uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @SP_Add_RetCode As int 


EXEC @SP_Add_RetCode = master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_primary_database 
        @database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@backup_directory = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@backup_share = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@backup_job_name = N'LSBackup_NewDB9' 
        ,@backup_retention_period = 360
        ,@backup_threshold = 60 
        ,@threshold_alert_enabled = 1
        ,@history_retention_period = 5760 
        ,@backup_job_id = @LS_BackupJobId OUTPUT 
        ,@primary_id = @LS_PrimaryId OUTPUT 
        ,@overwrite = 1 


IF (@@ERROR = 0 AND @SP_Add_RetCode = 0) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @LS_BackUpScheduleUID   As uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_BackUpScheduleID    AS int 


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule 
        @schedule_name =N'LSBackupSchedule_172.21.23.161' 
        ,@enabled = 1 
        ,@freq_type = 4 
        ,@freq_interval = 1 
        ,@freq_subday_type = 4 
        ,@freq_subday_interval = 15 
        ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 0 
        ,@active_start_date = 20241115 
        ,@active_end_date = 99991231 
        ,@active_start_time = 0 
        ,@active_end_time = 235900 
        ,@schedule_uid = @LS_BackUpScheduleUID OUTPUT 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_BackUpScheduleID OUTPUT 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule 
        @job_id = @LS_BackupJobId 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_BackUpScheduleID  

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job 
        @job_id = @LS_BackupJobId 
        ,@enabled = 1 


END 


EXEC master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_alert_job 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_primary_secondary 
        @primary_database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@secondary_server = N'172.21.23.17' 
        ,@secondary_database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@overwrite = 1 

-- ****** End: Script to be run at Primary: [172.21.23.16]  ******


-- Execute the following statements at the Secondary to configure Log Shipping 
-- for the database [172.21.23.17].[NewDB9],
-- the script needs to be run at the Secondary in the context of the [msdb] database. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- Adding the Log Shipping configuration 

-- ****** Begin: Script to be run at Secondary: [172.21.23.17] ******


DECLARE @LS_Secondary__CopyJobId    AS uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_Secondary__RestoreJobId AS uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_Secondary__SecondaryId  AS uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_Add_RetCode As int 


EXEC @LS_Add_RetCode = master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_secondary_primary 
        @primary_server = N'172.21.23.16' 
        ,@primary_database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@backup_source_directory = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@backup_destination_directory = N'/var/opt/mssql/shipping' 
        ,@copy_job_name = N'LSCopy_172.21.23.16_NewDB9' 
        ,@restore_job_name = N'LSRestore_172.21.23.16_NewDB9' 
        ,@file_retention_period = 4320 
        ,@overwrite = 1 
        ,@copy_job_id = @LS_Secondary__CopyJobId OUTPUT 
        ,@restore_job_id = @LS_Secondary__RestoreJobId OUTPUT 
        ,@secondary_id = @LS_Secondary__SecondaryId OUTPUT 

IF (@@ERROR = 0 AND @LS_Add_RetCode = 0) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @LS_SecondaryCopyJobScheduleUID As uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_SecondaryCopyJobScheduleID  AS int 


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule 
        @schedule_name =N'DefaultCopyJobSchedule' 
        ,@enabled = 1 
        ,@freq_type = 4 
        ,@freq_interval = 1 
        ,@freq_subday_type = 4 
        ,@freq_subday_interval = 15 
        ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 0 
        ,@active_start_date = 20241115 
        ,@active_end_date = 99991231 
        ,@active_start_time = 0 
        ,@active_end_time = 235900 
        ,@schedule_uid = @LS_SecondaryCopyJobScheduleUID OUTPUT 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_SecondaryCopyJobScheduleID OUTPUT 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule 
        @job_id = @LS_Secondary__CopyJobId 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_SecondaryCopyJobScheduleID  

DECLARE @LS_SecondaryRestoreJobScheduleUID  As uniqueidentifier 
DECLARE @LS_SecondaryRestoreJobScheduleID   AS int 


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule 
        @schedule_name =N'DefaultRestoreJobSchedule' 
        ,@enabled = 1 
        ,@freq_type = 4 
        ,@freq_interval = 1 
        ,@freq_subday_type = 4 
        ,@freq_subday_interval = 15 
        ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 0 
        ,@active_start_date = 20241115 
        ,@active_end_date = 99991231 
        ,@active_start_time = 0 
        ,@active_end_time = 235900 
        ,@schedule_uid = @LS_SecondaryRestoreJobScheduleUID OUTPUT 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_SecondaryRestoreJobScheduleID OUTPUT 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule 
        @job_id = @LS_Secondary__RestoreJobId 
        ,@schedule_id = @LS_SecondaryRestoreJobScheduleID  


END 


DECLARE @LS_Add_RetCode2    As int 


IF (@@ERROR = 0 AND @LS_Add_RetCode = 0) 
BEGIN 

EXEC @LS_Add_RetCode2 = master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_secondary_database 
        @secondary_database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@primary_server = N'172.21.23.16' 
        ,@primary_database = N'NewDB9' 
        ,@restore_delay = 0 
        ,@restore_mode = 1 
        ,@disconnect_users  = 0 
        ,@restore_threshold = 60   
        ,@threshold_alert_enabled = 1 
        ,@history_retention_period  = 5760 
        ,@overwrite = 1 

END 


IF (@@error = 0 AND @LS_Add_RetCode = 0) 
BEGIN 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job 
        @job_id = @LS_Secondary__CopyJobId 
        ,@enabled = 1 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job 
        @job_id = @LS_Secondary__RestoreJobId 
        ,@enabled = 1 

END 

-- ****** End: Script to be run at Secondary: [172.21.23.17] ******


Part ran on Primary server passed successfully. But part ran on Secondary server failed with this error:
Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure master.dbo.sp_add_log_shipping_secondary_database, Line 54 [Batch Start Line 0]
The database 'NewDB9' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.

I understand, error says that on Secondary server is not available database but task through GUI passed successfully, what means it is able to create database there.
Has anyone any clue, why task run via Transact-SQL failed ?

There's no code that actually takes full backup and restores it on secondary, which starts the chain
